# How do you get the total number of times a value/name occurs in a column in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a df which has multiple columns. How can I select one particular column out of these, and count the total number of times a particular name or value occurs in that column? For example, if I had the following:

1. **Country         Continent**
2. Egypt Africa
3. China Asia
4. India Asia
5. Poland Europe
6. Kenya Africa
7. Nepal Asia

For the above df, how would I get a tally of how many times each continent type occurs. So, for example, I should get that Asia occurs 3 times and Africa occurs 2 times. Any help would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

We can use `table`

```
table(df1$Continent)
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    count(Continent)
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply use this:

```
summary(df$Continent)
```